# Adding attributes to AutoCAD objects

Tags: fields-attributes, autocad, dxf

I am willing to add attributes to objects I drew. So if I create a rectangle I am willing to give it name and id attributes.  will see it on the dxf file as one of the attributes. Is there a way to do it?
I am using AutoCAD 2015 on Mac

Comment: Can be done but not easy or straightforward. CAD is not GIS and is not designed to be used in the same way.

Comment: A good question should show some research and attempt.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Please [edit] your question to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Please also take the new user [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Sounds like you need block attributes https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-67A2DDAD-2217-412F-8AEF-D4495192F45B-htm.html